# blackbox exporter ssh connection test problem

Tags: prometheus, sshd, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

guys:

i am using blackbox exporter to test many remote servers ssh port 22, the module is ssh_banner. The problem is it always print a log in remote server for each ssh test.:

```
Oct 20 10:23:14 hpit32 sshd[14073]: Did not receive identification string from ******
Oct 20 10:23:16 hpit32 sshd[14074]: Did not receive identification string from ******
```

does anyone know how to fix this problem without change sshd log level or any sshd configration.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no way around the log.This could lead to issues with fail2ban or sshguard; make sure the IP is in the exception list of your security system and use a reasonable scrape interval.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
  ssh_banner:
    prober: tcp
    timeout: 5s
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^SSH-2.0-"
      - send: "SSH-2.0-blackbox-ssh-check"
```

This already makes sshd happy.